# Where is the default Gem.dir path set?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

This is really odd:  I installed ruby 1.9.1 using a "191" suffix so that it will coexist with other versions.  e.g. the executables look like `ruby191`, `gem191` and the library directory where all of the vendor/site code lives is `/usr/local/lib/ruby191`.  The version of RubyGems (1.3.1) that is included with ruby 1.9.1 works fine.  The installation was performed with:

```
cd /usr/local/src/ruby-1.9.1-p429
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --program-suffix=191
make
sudo make install
```

However, when I upgrade my RubyGems installation with `sudo gem191 update --system` it appears to forget about all of the installed gems.  When I checked it out with `gem191 environment` it is now looking in `/usr/local/lib/ruby`.

I know I can create a `~/.gemrc` and change the location there, but that smells like a hack to me.  I have spent a couple of hours trying to figure out where `Gem.dir` is set in the code, but have been unable to find it.  Does anyone know where the default location is set?

Comment: How did you install exactly? Did you specify any compile flags?

Comment: Ruby was installed with:
    cd /usr/local/src/ruby-1.9.1-p429
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --program-suffix=191
    make
    sudo make install

Then updated RubyGems from the default 1.3.1 to 1.3.7 with:
    sudo gem191 update --system

Comment: Just realized that comments don't get formatted correctly -- edited original post to include the information.

Comment: you can use the ri_for gem to determine where bin_path is located (it just uses Method#source_location)

It's probably a bug in the rubygems autoupdater, it seems to me...

Comment: Yeah, it must be a bug.  I took an alternative approach that seems to be working so far:  I installed the entire ruby environment into its own directory without the suffix rather than trying to directly integrate it into the /usr/local/ hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the Gem engine didn't work properly under ruby 1.9.1, but has been fixed under ruby 1.9.2.  After installing the latest build, all of my Gem issues have disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use [rvm gem](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) for multiple ruby installations on one system.

P.S. You can view your gem installation path by using `$ gem{suffix} env`.

Comment: I mentioned trying this in my original post.  The path does indeed change.